# Proxied armature groups participating in rigid body simulations

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, linked-data

I have a multi shot production where the main character is going to be smashing a few things.

Our pipeline follows the standard set-up of a linked asset (main character) into an animation/lighting/rendering file. The main character is meshes that are deformed by an armature which is grouped in the main character file.

The group is then linked and proxied in the animation file. As he swings his tail around I want him to hit other objects participating in the rigid body (RB) simulation. This is where it breaks.

You can proxy a linked object and apply RB setting to it. Unfortunately it doesn't bring the RB settings across from the source file, but that's OK, it's only a couple of clicks to set it up again.

But if you proxy an armature/mesh group then you cannot add the RB settings, you can only add a force field or RB constraint. To make things trickier - it is a deforming mesh as well.

So does anyone know a way around this limitation? Appending the character is not an option (then we will lose any updates to the character).